# Asus UX430UQ, Ubuntu 17.10 - there are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

Tags: configuration, overheating, fan, fancontrol, heat

I just bought a new laptop (Asus UX430UQ) which has annoying fans that are turned on all the time, even when not needed (e.g. @30°C core temp).

I'm currently trying to get them under control with fancontrol.

These sensors are detected by `lm-sensors`:

```
patrick@patrick-UX430UQ:~$ sensors
iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +30.0°C  

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +31.0°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +35.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +35.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +33.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

When I try to access them with fancontrol (`sudo pwmconfig`), I receive the following message:

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

Maybe there really aren't pwm-capable sensors available, but if I don't get the fan under control I will return the laptop. That's why I want to try if it might still work.

I've already tried a solution that has worked for other people by adding `"acpi_enforce_resources=lax"` to */etc/defaults/grub* but didn't help on my laptop.

Any other suggestions?

Update (after installing NVIDIA drivers):
As per request here is my lsmod output

```
patrick@patrick-UX430UQ:~$ lsmod | grep "asus\|coretemp\|video"
uvcvideo                 90112  0
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
wmi                    24576  3 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi
asus_wireless          16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
video                  40960  2 asus_wmi,i915
```

Comment: My UX32A with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS reacts normally to `sudo pwmconfig`, it outputs *hwmon2/pwm1           current value: 255* and puts fans in full speed. Are you sure that the CPU is idle on 30C? Now I have 57C with 3800 RPM fan.

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `lsmod | grep "asus\|coretemp\|video"`. I have *asus_nb_wmi*, *asus_wmi*, *coretemp*, *i915* modules loaded. So `pwmconfig` detects fan's PWM with  *hwmon2 is asus*. I read your post again and I think that you should install proprietary NVIDIA drivers, because of bad power management in Nouveau. Nouveau is the problem, I think. Your laptop TTX looks good.

Comment: Hi N0rbert, thanks for your reply. I installed the NVIDIA drivers and added the lsmod output to the post. It's still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have no new ideas. Let's wait for other suggestions.

Comment: Still looking for an idea ;) 
For Windows there is a programm called NoteBook Fan Control that is in fact able to control and therefore slow down the fan at lower temperatures. That's why I can't believe that there is no solution for Ubuntu as well.